# Python iterable protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made an iterable Squares object in 4 way. The classical class, generator style and just for fun a closure style and an improved(?) closure style.

**class**

```
class Squares:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.SquaresIterator(self.n)

    class SquaresIterator:
        def __init__(self, n):
            self.n = n
            self.i = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self.i >= self.n:
                raise StopIteration

            result = self.i ** 2
            self.i += 1
            return result
```

It works as expected

```
sq_class = Squares(5)
list(sq_class)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
# calling again will create a new iterator
list(sq_class)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

**generator**

```
def squares(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i ** 2

sq_gen = squares(5)
list(sq_gen)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
# calling again will return empty [] is OK, generator exhausted.
list(sq_gen)
[]
```

**closure**

```
def Squares(n):
    def inner():
        return squares_gen(n)

    def squares_gen(n):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i ** 2

    return inner

sq_closure = Squares(5)
list(sq_closure())
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
# calling again the inner will create a new generator so it is not exhausted
list(sq_closure())
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

**improved(?) closure**

```
def Squares(n):
    def inner():
        return squares_gen(n)

    def squares_gen(n):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i ** 2

    inner.__iter__ = lambda : squares_gen(n)
    return inner

sq_closure = Squares(5)
list(sq_closure)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-beb02e61ccfb> in <module>
----> 1 for i in sq:
      2     print(i)

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

What I wanted to try is attach the `__iter__` function to the inner function object and return a generator and I can leave the ()-s and I can use the returned inner as an iterable object. 
What is the exact definition of the iterable protocol? It seems, only the presence of the `__iter__` function is not enough.

Comment: Magicmethods are only invoked when they are class attributes - you cannot set them as instance attributes (well you can but they wont be invoked <g>).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133096/assigning-instead-of-defining-a-getitem-magic-method-breaks-indexing

Comment: Thx bruno for the answer +1.

Comment: You missed the simplest way, which is to just use the built-in tools for generating infinite sequences: `squares = map(lambda x: x*x, itertools.count())` or `squares  = (x*x for x in itertools.count())`. Use `islice` to take a finite prefix of the sequence: `list(itertools.islice(squares, 5)) == [0,1,4,9,16]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "exact definition of the iterable protocol" [is in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

> iterable:
>   An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include (...) objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` method or with a `__getitem__()` method that implements Sequence semantics.

BUT: `__magicmethods__` are [only invoked when defined on the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133096/assigning-instead-of-defining-a-getitem-magic-method-breaks-indexing) - you cannot override them on a per-instance basis (well you can but they won't be invoked).